# Certificate problems with Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, certificate

Ok I have 2 Exchange 2007 servers, and a Edgesync server.

I noticed they had old certificates on them, and I installed stand alone Cert. Authority on them and gave them a new certificate (I backed up the old one just in case)

When I did that OWA stopped working, Out of Office Assitant stopped working, and edgesynce won't send out messages due to security policies.

I tried removing the Cert Authorities, removed new certs, and replaced with old certs..stuff is not working. How do I fix this fowl up.

Comment: This is going to need a lot more information. How did you sign the new certificates? What commands did you run to install them? What errors are you getting with the broken services? Have you run through https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ yet? (It is an MS service and it is legit)

Comment: Do you need your OWA system to be usable with external browsers without errors?  If so then you need to pay for certificates.  If your old certificates are expired, they need to be replaced.  If you acquired them from public CAs then you need to pay to renew.

Answer (score 0):

If the old cert was self-signed then the following should resolve it:

Using the Certificates snap-in in the MMC or the Get-ExchangeCertificate command in the exchange management shell get the thumbprint of the cert.

Get-ExchangeCertificate -thumbprint thumbprint_of_cert | New-ExchangeCertificate

Get-ExchangeCertificate (to verify expiration date and thumbprint of new cert)

Enable-ExchangeCertificate -thumbprint new_cert_thumbprint

IIS,SMTP,POP,IMAP